# Find difference between timestamps in seconds in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in `PostgreSQL 8.3` with 2 `timestamp` columns. I would like to get the difference between these `timestamps` in seconds. Could you please help me how to get this done?

```
TableA
(
  timestamp_A timestamp,
  timestamp_B timestamp
)
```

I need to get something like `(timestamo_B - timestamp_A)` in seconds *(not just the difference between seconds, it should include hours, minutes etc)*.

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp_B - timestamp_A))
FROM TableA
```

Details here: [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It worked !!! In the above query, we are missing a closing parenthesis . But I have figured it out. Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Answer (score 46):

```
select age(timestamp_A, timestamp_B)
```

---

Answering to Igor's comment:

```
select age('2013-02-28 11:01:28'::timestamp, '2011-12-31 11:00'::timestamp);
              age              
-------------------------------
 1 year 1 mon 28 days 00:01:28
```

Comment: It wont do the job. It will `Subtract arguments, producing a "symbolic" result that uses years and months`. It wont give the difference in seconds.

Comment: @Igor Updated with the results including seconds. The OP wants not only seconds but also minutes, hours, etc

Comment: If I understood him correctly, he wants `to get the difference between these timestamps in seconds`. And `it should include hours, minutes etc` means it must be the full difference like `10:25:30 - 10:15:25 = 605 seconds`. My guess - he used `EXTRACT(SECONDS FROM ...)` and got `10:25:30 - 10:15:25 = 5 seconds`

Comment: @Igor It is not very clear but now that you say it I think you are probably right.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: I need the output as mentioned by Igor. I need the full difference in seconds.

Comment: What if I only need a month difference from this query?

Comment: well butter my biscuit