# How do you get the difference between two "timestamps with/without timezone" in seconds using dplyr?

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

When a in-database (PostgreSQL) `dplyr::mutate` operation calculates the difference between two timestamps, a character vector is returned, each element of the form like:

```
> RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(db$con, 'select now() - current_date;')
         ?column?
1 09:23:48.880493
```

In this case it is `HH:MM:SS.ssssss`. How do I get `dplyr` to return this vector of time differences in seconds? That is, I would like to do the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020919/find-difference-between-timestamps-in-seconds-in-postgresql), except have it as part of a `mutate` statement.

Example `dplyr` code would be:

```
tbl(db$con, 'tmp_table') %>%
    mutate(time_diff = received_at - started_at) %>%
    select(id, time_diff) %>%
    collect(n = Inf)
```

Comment: why not just `select extract(epoch from now() - current_date)` stright in SQL?..

Comment: I am using the `dplyr` language to build a complex query and I do not wish to translate the whole thing into SQL, also, as part of the pipe I copy data to the database from `R` in order to do joins.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a satisfactory answer to me, but a roundabout way of doing it is:

```
tmp_table <-
tbl(db$con, 'tmp_table') %>%
    mutate(time_diff = received_at - started_at) %>%
    select(id, time_diff) %>%
    compute() # creates a temporary table
```

You can then find the name of the temporary table using:

```
as.character(tmp_table$ops$x$x)
```

In my case this was `[1] "rzlhbxogjx"`. Then, using the linked answer you could do:

```
RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(db$con, 
              paste0("select id, extract(epoch from time_diff) 
              as time_diff from ", as.character(tmp_table$ops$x$x), ";")
```