# how to calculate the time between two timestamps (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Calculate the time between these two timestamps in **PostgreSQL**, 
`create_time='2017-11-02 05:51:13' and update_time='2017-11-02 07:36:18'` 
and display it on *`HH:MM:SS`* Format. it should display like this *01:45:04*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find difference between timestamps in seconds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020919/find-difference-between-timestamps-in-seconds-in-postgresql)

Comment: What is the desired result if the timestamps are on different days?

Comment: @IvanAracki I don't think this is an exact duplicate of that question, because the OP wants the time portion of the timestamp, not just seconds (or minutes, etc.).

Comment: What if the difference is bigger than one day? What do you want to see then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just subtracting the two timestamps, then using `to_char` to extract out the time portion:

```
select
    SELECT to_char('2017-11-02 07:36:18'::timestamp -
                   '2017-11-02 05:51:10'::timestamp, 'HH:MI:SS');
```

**Output:**

```
to_char
01:45:08
```

## Demo