# Find difference between timestamps in seconds in PostgreSQL using JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq, sql-timestamp, timestampdiff

I need to **find the difference between two timestamps in seconds using JOOQ**.
I have taken a look at some answers on StackOverflow using raw SQL, however i didn´t find a way to implement it using JOOQ.

Here are some solutions that i found that are using raw SQL:

- [Find difference between timestamps in seconds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020919/find-difference-between-timestamps-in-seconds-in-postgresql)
- [MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DSL.timestampDiff(timestamp1, timestamp2)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#timestampDiff-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-). It will return the difference in terms of an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` type: [`org.jooq.types.DayToSecond`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/types/DayToSecond.html)

Comment: This won't return the diff in seconds, will it?

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Even better, you'll get an interval type from which you can extract the seconds. I'm happy to answer a new question about some specific usage (which your current question didn't mention), in case this isn't sufficient

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as i get it, your proposed solution requires me to convert the `org.jooq.types.DayToSecond` field from my result record to seconds using Java. Is it possible to use the DB for converting the interval to seconds?

Comment: I have added some more information to the question.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Thanks for your edit. Just a hint for using Stack Overflow: Your edit really changes the question and makes it confusing for future readers. I think it would be better to simply ask a new question and revert this one to the old version, which was useful as well...

Comment: I´ve create a follow up question. It would be great if you could take another look :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961787/find-and-sum-difference-between-timestamps-in-seconds-in-postgresql-using-jooq