# Compute Difference Between Two Timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, datediff, sql-timestamp

I have two `Timestamp` columns in a PostgreSQL table (e.g, `2019-07-12 07:59:59`). I need to subtract two columns and save the (`HH:MM:SS`) value under new name?

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020919/find-difference-between-timestamps-in-seconds-in-postgresql

Comment: I don't want to change the format into seconds.... Final subtracted value should be like hh:mm:ss?

Comment: You combine it with a conversion of second into HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to compute the epoch. Subtraction of timestamps gives an interval which directly converted:

```
with timestamps (tsa, tsb) as 
     (values ('2020-01-15T06:15:00'::timestamp, '2020-01-15T18:15:00'::timestamp)) 
select to_char(tsb-tsa,'hh24:mi:ss') from timestamps;
```

Answer (score 0):

You combine the two:
First get the difference in seconds and convert seconds in hhmmss:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((EXTRACT(EPOCH 
               FROM (timestamp_B - timestamp_A)) || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```